# google script - require string input before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I use a little script based on html and javascript to enable third parties to upload files to my drive. They are supposed to name the file so that I can identify it later on. Unfortunately many forget to do so. Which changes are necessary to force input in myName before submitting?

html code

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="name of the file..">
<input type="file" name="myFile">
<input type="submit" value="Abschicken" 
onclick="this.value='Please wait..';
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
.uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
return false;">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
function fileUploaded(status) {
document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}
</script>
<style>
input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

google script

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}
function uploadFiles(form) {
    try {
      var dropbox = "Fotos";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
     if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Projekt: " + form.myName);
    file.setName("FOTO_" + form.myName);
    return "Upload completed.";
    } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add te required attribute to the form.

```
<input type="text" required name="myName" placeholder="name of the file..">
```

This will cause the browser to check that a value is entered before submitting the form. If the field is empty the browser will show an error and won't submit the form.

The user could still remove the required attribute but since you don't have access to the server side this is the best you can do.